# Stream through collection and filter using a priority

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to filter a collection based on a certain priority.
The collection consists of entities with fields of a certain type.

So, I would like to do the following:
Iterate/Stream through the collection and

1. Find the first entity which has a getType = "type1". If this entity has a price > 0 then return this entity. Otherwise
2. Find the next entity which has a getType = "type2". If this has a price > 0 then return this. Otherwise
3. Find the next entity which has a getType = "type3". If this has a price > 0 then return this.
4. Find the next entity which has a getType = "type4". If this has a price > 0 then return this.
5. Find the next entity which has a getType = "type5". If this has a price > 0 then return this.
6. Otherwise return.

I am trying to do this using stream but the filter step is where I am unable to create this priority type of filtering. I also tried to loop through the collection using a for, however not sure how to implement `findFirst` entity of type1, then type2 etc..

Comment: Share youe tried please

Comment: post your code, madam

Comment: `6. Otherwise return` but what? If method is declared to return some value then it needs to return something, or throw exception.

Comment: To avoid possible mistakes in interpretation of the problem could you [edit] your question and include few examples of stream of elements like `(T1, 0), (T1, 10), (T2, 0), (T3, 5), (T4, 0), (T5, 0)` along with expected results and some reasons why it is expected?

Comment: Assume the object has multiples of any type with price > 0,  which do you want?

Comment: @Pshemo According to the rules listed, it should return `(T3, 5)`. After finding the first T1, it will never look for other T1's, so `(T1, 10)` will not be returned.

Comment: @WJS According to the rules listed, it should return the first one found.

Comment: I believe the *best* answer for this question is that Streams is the **wrong tool** for the job. If it *must* be done with streams, a custom `Collector` would be needed.

Comment: @Andreas  I reread the requirement and I had glazed over *find the `first` entry of Type1*.   now I see it.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that would be expected result using rules written in the question but still I would like to get some examples from OP since those conditions feel quite unique which makes me think that maybe they are not phrased correctly and may not express what OP *really* wants.

Comment: @Pshemo I agree with you, which is why I conditioned my comment with "According to the rules listed". I actually added the comment, more to showcase how the rules might be badly written, because if that's not the outcome OP wanted, OP should react to that. We'll see, once OP eventually comes back online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a clarification by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) and a strict interpretation of the requirements as **presently stated**, this should work.

- I basically streamed the `types` and then substreamed the `list`.
- The inner stream is checked for each type in priority order.
- if the first one found has a positive price it is returned.
- else the next type is checked and the process repeated
- In the event nothing matches, a special object is returned.

Class used to verify.

```
class MyClass {
    private int price;
    private String type;
    
    public MyClass(int price, String type) {
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s]", price, type);
    }
}
```

Data

```
List<MyClass> list = List.of(new MyClass(0, "Type1"),
        new MyClass(10, "Type2"), new MyClass(2, "Type1"),
        new MyClass(2, "Type4"), new MyClass(2, "Type5"),
        new MyClass(2, "Type2"), new MyClass(10, "Type1"),
        new MyClass(1, "Type2"), new MyClass(2, "Type5"));

String[] types =
        { "Type1", "Type2", "Type3", "Type4", "Type5" };
```

Solution

```
MyClass selected = Arrays.stream(types)
        .map(type -> list.stream()
                .filter(obj -> obj.getType().equals(type))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null))
        .filter(a -> a != null && a.getPrice() > 0)
        .findFirst().orElse(new MyClass(-1, "Empty"));

System.out.println(selected);
```

Prints

```
[10, Type2]
```

Comment: The code doesn't work for this: `(T2, 6), (T1, 0), (T1, 10), (T3, 7), (T2, 0), (T3, 5), (T4, 0), (T5, 0)` --- Correct result would be **`(T3, 5)`**, but code prints `(T2, 6)`.

Comment: So your saying that if the only T1 was at the end of the list and the price was 0 there would be no object selected, no matter how many others were ahead,  right!

Comment: My error is that I restart the inner stream from the beginning instead of from the previous failure.  A subtlety I missed.  It will be interesting to see if all this is what the OP had in mind.

Comment: It is what the rules say, but yeah, only OP can clarify if that's how it was intended to work. It is so frigging irritating when people can't write the requirements correctly, but you can't hit the customer in the face when they do it, again and again, you just have to bite the bullet and *charge them extra*. 

Comment: This does not work when we have 2 T1 one with a price of null and one with price >0. It seems to pick the one with price = null due to the firstFind. I tried to tweak the filter to find the First type1 which has a price != null and >0 but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

If you rephrase the requirement a bit, it makes the translation to a series of operations of a stream much clearer - you should return the first item with `price > 0` that has the minimal `type`:

```
MyEntity result = myList.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getPrice() > 0)
                        .min(Compartor.comparing(MyEntity::getType))
                        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: That may be what OP needs, but it is not what the requirements state. Find the *first* type 1, and stop search if `price > 0`. Otherwise look for the *next* type 2, i.e. a type 2 following that type 1. **Conclusion 1:** Any type 1 following the first will be ignored. **Conclusion 2:** Any type 2 preceding the first type 1 will be ignored.

Comment: @Andreas How does this conflict with the requirements?  Any answer must have price >0.  And then you just take the minimum object based on Type?  Can you provide a counter example where this would not work?

Comment: With `myList = [type2[price=7], type1[price=0], type2[price=11]]` the code returns `type2[price=7]`. If you following the rules strictly: 1) *"Find the first entity which has a getType = "type1"."* So we find `type1[price=0]`. *"If this entity has a price > 0 then return this entity. Otherwise"* Since price is not >0, we do otherwise: 2) *"Find the next entity which has a getType = "type2"."* The ***next*** entity with type2 is `type2[price=11]`. *"If this has a price > 0 then return this." So we must return **`type2[price=11]`**.

Comment: Actually, it is undefined what `min()` returns when there are multiple elements with the minimum value. Most commonly, such an operation returns the first, but as it is *undefined*, it could return either `type2[price=7]` or `type2[price=11]`. If the stream is parallel, I believe the result truly would be arbitrary, since there is no ordering guarantee for the result. --- The result still deviates from the strict interpretation of the rules.

Comment: @WJS - thank you for taking the time to respond. The code fails when I have say (Type1,null),(Type1,100),(Type2,10). It picks up Type2,10 as the findFirst picked Type1,null instead of Type1,100. I am trying to filter the findFirst to include the price as well but it doesnt seem to work correctly

Comment: I used for the most part,  the solution provided by @WJS .Tweaked it a bit, to get rid of nulls and zero first, then used that collection to stream through and pick the first type that met the condition.Thank you all for the solutions and tips that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

**Original - Invalid reduction Approach**

One option is to flip the order of operations. Ex: filter where 'price > 0' and then reduce the stream as elements are encountered. Ex:

```
stream.filter(elem -> elem.price > 0)
    .reduce((elem1, elem2) -> elem1.type.compareTo(elem2.type) < 0 ? elem1 : elem2)
```

**Edit - More correct reduction approach**

In general, it is best to keep stream operations stateless. Because of this creating a function which handles iterating through the list and returning the result may be a more correct approach. Using streams, a custom 'reducer' may be defined which keeps track of the prior type checked to determine if the next result is a possible valid match. Once a valid match is found, it is always returned.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Entity> data = Arrays.asList(eee(2, 6), eee(1, 0), eee(1, 10), eee(3, 7), eee(2, 0), eee(3, 5), eee(4, 0), eee(5, 0));
        System.out.println(data.stream().reduce(new Reducer()).filter(entity -> entity != Reducer.NO_MATCH));
    }

    /*Once a match is found, always use it. For a given type, only the first found entity of that type will be used*/
    public static final class Reducer implements BinaryOperator<Entity>
    {
        private int priorValidType;
        Reducer(){ this.priorValidType = 0; }

        @Override
        public Entity apply(Entity result, Entity newElem)
        {
            int nextValidType = priorValidType + 1;
            if(priorValidType > 0 && result != NO_MATCH) return result; /*Match already found, use it*/
            if(result.type == nextValidType && result.price > 0) { priorValidType = nextValidType; return result; } /*result is a match*/
            if(newElem.type == nextValidType && newElem.price > 0) { priorValidType = nextValidType; return newElem; } /*newElem is a match*/
            if(result.type == nextValidType || newElem.type == nextValidType) { priorValidType = nextValidType; }
            return NO_MATCH; /*No match has been found*/
        }

        public static final Entity NO_MATCH = new Entity(-1, -1);
    }

    public static final class Entity
    {
        private final int price, type;
        Entity(int type, int price){ this.price = price; this.type = type; }
        public String toString(){ return "(" + type + ", " + price + ")"; }
        int getPrice(){ return price; }
        int getType(){ return type; }
        public static Entity eee(int type, int price){ return new Entity(type, price); }
    }
```

**Edit - Alternative approach using filter**

A filter may be created which does something similar to the reduce approach, and will have the benefit of short circuiting when calling 'findFirst'. In the below, the first filter only allows the first encounter with a given type (in order) to pass through. The second filter confirms it is valid.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Entity> data = Arrays.asList(eee(2, 6), eee(1, 0), eee(1, 10), eee(3, 7), eee(2, 0), eee(3, 5), eee(4, 0), eee(5, 0));
        System.out.println(data.stream().filter(new FirstTypeMatch()).filter(entity -> entity.price > 0).findFirst());
    }

    /*Filter where the element is the first of the given type*/
    public static final class FirstTypeMatch implements Predicate<Entity>
    {
        private int priorValidType = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean test(Entity nextElem)
        {
            if(nextElem.type == (priorValidType + 1)){ priorValidType++; return true; }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The element has not been defined to implement `Comparable`. Even if it does, it has not been defined to compare primarily by `type`. Even if it does, the `reduce()` is the same as `min()`, so my comments to [answer by Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63945541/5221149) about this type of solution applies here as well.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Tweaked the above to correct the Comparable issue. I tend to agree that with the problem as stated streams may not be the best tool.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of using stream to sort it first based on Type(assuming type is in lowercase) and then using filter to filter out the negative price and then used findFirst to store it in Optional Entity

```
Optional<Entity> entity = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entity::getType))
.filter( e -> e.price > 0 ).findFirst();
     

if(entity.isPresent()){
    System.out.println(entity.get().getType()); // test to verify 
}
```

Comment: Please see my comments to [answer by Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63945541/5221149). They apply to this answer as well.